# EmberJS - Handling 3rd party redirect authentication

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I'm using [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) for my Ember app, but I don't have an API endpoint to authenticate users, rather it does a page redirect to the form and signs a user in, then redirects back to my app. (I don't own the authentication)

After authentication, it gets redirected back to me, so I know on the server side when a user has been successfully authenticated. How do I manually authenticate the users' session when they are redirected back to my app?

Currently I did a hack to write two cookies: `ember_simple_auth:access_token` and `ember_simple_auth:authenticator`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think setting up the session store manually is an ok solution in this scenario as that will trigger the session to be restored after the redirect (which is on startup of the Ember application). I'd maybe configure a custom authenticator that redirects to the external login page in the `authenticate` method. That way you have that redirect centralized and it will also be triggered automatically whenever Ember Simple Auth automatically enforces session authentication (e.g. from the `AuthenticatedRouteMixin`).

Comment: Thanks for your input @marcoow, how does it handle callbacks? With this method, ember-simple-auth doesn't know that it's a new log in, and `sessionAuthenticationSucceeded` wouldn't fire.

Comment: Yes, the `sessionAuthenticationSucceeded` event isn't triggered in this case as that event is only for the case when the session transitions from not being authenticated to authenticated during the runtime of your app. In your case thought the app always starts either authenticated or not so the event never triggers. You could register an initializer to run after the `'simple-auth'` initializer and do your set there depending on whether the session is authenticated or not.